# Google Play Games I can't authorize my linked app after I put my SHA1

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games

I am trying to authorize my android app. I entered the correct package name and the SHA1 I used to sign my apk, which I generated using unity. When I press confirm it tells me "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EZr1.png)

Comment: It is possible there's a conflict from your SHA1 and your package name. Please check thoroughly if the SHA1 have not used by other package name.

Comment: I connected my app to firebase first. with the same package name and SHA1. would that effect it?

Comment: Yes that would affect. Every package must have one unique SHA1.

Comment: But the documentation said to connect it to firebase first : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/play-games

Although it is not clear how to link the app to google play services. Plus, I used another package name with new SHA1 and it just gave me the same error. I even created new game in the console that is not connected to firebase. then used new package and a new SHA1 put it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for some reason now the play console started telling me what was the problem instead of just saying "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."!!

The problem was as [jess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10105321/jess) said, there shouldn't be two apps with the same package name and SHA-1. I linked my app to firebase first (I was following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/play-games)). then created a new project in the Play console linking it to my firebase project. my android app from firebase should've appeared in the Play console put it didn't for some reason. So, it was giving me error when I was trying to link my app to the Play console.

So, after Play console mysteriously started giving me the error message. I created new SHA-1 and add new app to the Play console. I wrote new package name, put the new SHA-1, and it worked. My app was authorized and was also shown on my linked firebase project.

I really think google did fixed something. because I sent them a message about it. Although they only replayed by give us more information.